# て form and adverbial meaning

Tags: grammar, て-form

While reading I sometimes come across some sentences like

> 包丁を使ってたまねぎを切った。

Where 使って is word just like an adverb which modifies 切る.

So I looked up a little more about the Te form and I found this:

> 付帯状況

Which I think it shows how you do the main verb using the Te form verb before it as an adverb which modifies the main verb.

Could someone give me a good explanation about Te form and 付帯状況?
Is the Te form just an adverb?
Or is it like a relative clause but instead of making a relative about a noun it makes an adverbial clause which shows how the next verb is done?

(The the form somehow reminds me of V1ことで...V2, by doing (through) V1 I do V2 or V1 is how I do V2. This is just how my mind sees it and I don't claim that is correct, but can someone tell me if I am wrong?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's adverb**ial** in relation to the verb (predicate), but you can't say it's simply an adverb (you can't use a te-form verb alone as an adverb). The word 付帯状況 literally means "collateral situation" (I wasn't able to find a proper English translation) that means what you're doing alongside doing action that is described with main verb, such as:

> 彼は時計を見てため息をついた。
>
> → *Looking at the watch, he gave a sigh.*
> → *He looked at the watch, and gave a sigh.*

The two translations are telling almost the same thing, but if you translate like the former one, it becomes an adverbial clause, while the latter looks more like [serial verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb_construction). Te-form can represent a wide range of relations between verbs, from almost independent two actions (酒を飲んで肉を食べる) to almost subordinate (包丁を使ってたまねぎを切る), depending on the context.

～を使って leans particularly to the subordinate side, as it always expects a verb that comes after it when it's used. Therefore, the phrase is usually translated as single words such as *using* or *with*.

Comment: When I find verbs like によって、において、にとって should I always expect another verb after that?

Comment: @Splikie Yes, because they take te-form that cannot end sentences. If you see no verb after, then something must be left unsaid.