# What does 思ってやっている mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

こんにちは! I have read a text about a guy whose wife has a housedust  allergie, and there is this sentence:
私だってあんまりほこりがたまっていたら気になるから、仕方がないと思ってやっているんだ。
What  does 思ってやって mean here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This やる is a simple verb meaning "to do". やっているんだ is "(It's that) I'm doing it", where this `'it'` refers to the thing this guy is doing. (It's not mentioned in your question, so see the previous context by yourself.) And 仕方がないと思って is modifying やっている [like an adverb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010).

> 「仕方がない」と思ってやっているんだ。
>   (literally) Thinking "it cannot be helped", I'm doing it.
>   I'm (reluctantly) doing this because I know it's unavoidable.