# How to say "too quickly", "too recklessly" etc

Tags: grammar

When I want to say that something is too quick, just as an example, I can simply say

> 速すぎる。

However, I don't quite know how I could express sentences with "too" adverbially, such as in "I became sick because I ate the cake too quickly".

I came up with these two translations for the example above:

> 1. ケーキの食べ方が速すぎて病気になってしまいました。
> 2. ケーキを食べるのが速すぎて病気になってしまいました。

Do these convey the intented meaning? What would be more natural alternatives? And lastly, and I'm sorry for straying a little bit away from the original question here: Is 病気になる a natural way to say "become sick" in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [て form and adverbial meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38769/%e3%81%a6-form-and-adverbial-meaning)

Comment: I think the translations you came up with are correct. See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38781/32952) for more insight on how to use the ~て form of a verb adverbially.

Comment: By the way, if you have several questions I kindly suggest you to create several Stack questions for each one, even if they came up from one single sentence you are thinking about.

Comment: If you want to dig a tiny bit deeper into the acceptability of `速く食べ過ぎた`, and of other alternatives to conveying this meaning, here is [an interesting thread](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3280573.html) on this very topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sentences are grammatical and natural-sounding (except for the use of 「病気になる」, which I will come back to later).

We say:

> 「Action A + の + が + 速{はや}すぎて + Action B」 ← The 「の」 is a nominalizer.

> 「Action A + 方{かた} + が + 速{はや}すぎて + Action B」 ← Use the continuative form for the verb in Action A -- 食べ方、歩き方、話し方、やり方, etc.

> 「Action A + の/方 + が + 速すぎる/すぎた + ため（に） + Action B」

Your two sentences are good because you used the first two of the three patterns above.

The mistake I occasionally see in Japanese-learners trying to express this is where they directly translate from English and end up saying it like:

・「速すぎて食べる」

・「速すぎる食べる」

Those sound highly unnatural and ungrammatical.  **In Japanese, you cannot use 「速すぎる・速すぎて」 to directly modify a verb the same way you can use "too quickly" to modify a verb in English**.

Finally, regarding 「病気になる」.  This phrase sounds far more serious than the English "to become or feel sick" for eating something too quickly.  「病気になる」 means none other than "to incur a disease".

The verb phrase that would fit in your sentences much better would be 「（気持{きも}ち / 気分{きぶん}）が悪{わる}くなる」.

Comment: How about ケーキを**速く食べすぎて**気持ち悪くなった ?

Comment: めっちゃ自然な表現やがな。なんで思いつかへんかったんやろ。おおきに～

Comment: What about "あまりに"? Something like "ケーキを**あまりに**速く食べて気持ち悪くなった"?