# Specific question about the use of "sugiru"

Tags: grammar, meaning

I learned you can use stem + sugiru, I adj - i + sugiru and na adj - na + sugiru to say "too much".

How would you translate "I woke up too early"?

- Hayasugiru okimashita
- Hayaku okisugimashita

Or neither?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70482/how-to-say-too-quickly-too-recklessly-etc/70490#_=_

Answer (score 1):

On the internet, you'll find「早{はや}く起{お}きすぎた」and「起{お}きるのが早{はや}すぎた」to express "I woke up too early." I'm not sure why that first sentence works, but perhaps someone can clarify that in the comments.

Comment: the first one 「早{はや}く起{お}きすぎた」is exactly like "Hayaku okisugimashita" only with casual past (た) instead of polite ました。