# Is it accurate to think of the て-form as meaning "in the state/condition/form of"?

Tags: grammar

It is difficult to rationslise the て-form of Japanese verbs in the mind of a speaker of an Indoeuropean language because there isn't something directly equivalent. However, it's been a few years now that this concept popped into my head that there is an implied meaning within the て-form as meaning "in the state/condition/form of". This to me makes sense with the te iru structure:

私はリンゴを食べている
Literally: I exist in the state of eating an apple.

I just wanted to see if this thought goes in the correct direction in relation to the て-form.

Comment: If you are being very literal, which here you are, I would agree. The te-form could be seen as a state or condition.

Comment: Related (See the 'older version' of question):
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78891/where-do-dictionaries-imply-the-use-of-%e3%81%a6-as-present-perfect-past-and-ing