# What is the use of で here?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-で

In the sentence “レジャーが目的で行く“ what does the で　express here?
Does に work here?
I was trying to compare it to the 〜しに行く, like 勉強しに行く．I understand that 目的 is a noun so there is no ます form. What if I want to say “for the purpose of flower viewing”. Where 花見 can be both a noun and a verb?
Do I say “花見をしに行く” or “花見が目的で行く”？

Answer (score 1):

This で is "the te-form of だ". Since 目的 is a noun, you need a copula (だ). It's in the te-form to [express "collateral situation"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010). If you know how 歩いて学校へ行く ("go to school on foot") or ハサミを使って紙を切る ("cut paper using scissors") works, レジャーが目的で行く is constructed in the same way; レジャーが目的で describes how the following action (行く) is achieved.

You cannot say レジャー**が**目的**に**行く, but you can say レジャー**を**目的**に**行く, which uses the [`AをBに` pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73094/5010).

In the case of 花見, you can say one of 花見をしに行く, 花見に行く, 花見を目的に行く, and 花見が目的で行く.