# Interpreting これからもAしてBしよう

Tags: grammar

Does これからも and apply to both or just to B?

Example:

> よーし！ 私これからも 防御に特化してプレイしよう

Does it mean

> Alright, let's keep specializing in defense and playing! [We've been already doing both.]

or

> Alright, let's specialize in defense and keep playing! [We've been already playing, but didn't specialize in defense until now.]

Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this 防御に特化して is adverbially modifying プレイする. That is, it says "to play it specializing in defense" or "to play with a dedicated defensive style", not "to specialize in defense *and then* play". Therefore これからも applies to both as a set. The sentence means "Let's keep playing [it] with a dedicated defensive style!"

Remember that te-form can explain how the second action is done:

- 歩いて学校に行く
  to go to school on foot
  <sub>(Not: to walk and then go to school)</sub>
- ナイフを使って紙を切る
  to cut paper with a knife
  <sub>(Not: to use a knife and then cut paper)</sub>

See: [て form and adverbial meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010)

Comment: I was puzzled by the 私 in the original sentence and the OP's translation as "let's". Am I missing something? Is it not just "**I** will keep ..."

Comment: @user3856370 She's talking to herself. I was hoping that "let's do this" conveys the meaning correctly. I could have translated it as "Alright, I'll keep playing ...", but wouldn't that lose the nuance of しよう?